# Append items to MultipleSectionModel

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, rxdatasources

I follow this [sample](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxDataSources/blob/master/Example/Example4_DifferentSectionAndItemTypes.swift) and successfully created multi-section `tableView`, but how can I append items to one of this sections? I can recreate the section but I want to append items instead of reloading `tableView`.

Comment: did u use "beginUpdate" and "endUpdate" methods of tableview.? In between these methods u can insert item with section and index.

Comment: It's not compatible with RxDataSource, so any changes must be made against dataSource not the table view

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
self.sections[lastSectionIndex].items.append(newItem)
```

where `lastSectionIndex` is the index for the section you want to update its items.

Also, I recommend you use `Variable` for your sections model for seamless updates.